# Karma-Jasmine: Error: Unexpected request: POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

**THE SITUATION:**

I am testing a POST http request in my angular app.

I have made several attempts but i am always getting the following error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: POST http://my_api.com/accountLogin 
No more request expected
```

**THE FUNCTION:**

The function will submit the login data and will get '1' as response if the data inserted are correct.

```
$scope.submit_login = function() 
{
    $http.post('http://my_api.com/accountLogin', {"api_access_key": $rootScope.access_key,  "email": $scope.loginData.email, "password": $scope.loginData.password}, {"headers" : { "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" }}).
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
    {
        $scope.result = data;
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
    {
        console.log('error ');
    });

};
```

**THE TEST:**

The aim is to mock the response as 1 and expect $scope.result = 1

```
describe('My account functions test', function() 
{

    beforeEach(inject(function() 
    {
        var mockLoginResponse = 1;

        $httpBackend
         .when('POST', 'http://my_api.com/accountLogin','{"headers" : { "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" }}',
         { 
            api_access_key: 'hardcode_access_key',
            email: 'hardcoded_email',
            password: 'hardcoded_password' 
         })  
         .respond(200, mockLoginResponse);

    }));


    it('submit_login() properly working', function() 
    {
        $scope.submit_login();
        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect($scope.result).toEqual( 1 );
    });

});
```

**THE QUESTION:**

Why am I getting that error?

What I am doing wrong?

Is this the proper way to test POST request?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the expectation definition.  See below - documentation with example which shows the expectation can be found here - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend.

```
it('submit_login() properly working', function() 
    {
        $httpBackend.expectPOST('http://my_api.com/accountLogin'); //This is what you are missing
        $scope.submit_login();
        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect($scope.result).toEqual( 1 );
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! Is almost working. It works and the test passes if i leave the api address only without header and data. If i pass along the header and the data i get a strange error. I have tried modified every little character but still I am getting it: Error: Expected POST http://my_api.com/accountLogin with different data
EXPECTED: {"api_access_key": "hardcoded_access_key","email": "hardcoded_email","password": "hardcoded_password"}
GOT:      {"api_access_key":"hardcoded_access_key"}

Comment: I don't have to pass the header and data in the expectPOST?

Comment: 1) I would not worry about the headers unless you needed to test special logic with it.  Simple tests are my goal :)

Comment: 2) Your syntax is off for your .when definition.  You have data and headers flip-flopped in your previous example (.when(method, url, [data], [headers], [keys]);).  Also, I would recommend using the object notation for the headers object.  I did not test but the documentation states it the headers parameter only accept and Object and function(Object), not string like the data attribute does.